# javascript regex object vs inline regex

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have to count occurences of symbols from the list (var. "pattern") in each string (element) of array. I want to make it more universal, by setting pattern in variable. But, when I try to do it by using RegExp object, it doesn't work.

I can't understand the difference in two parts of code:

This variant doesn't work.

```
var pattern = "@#%";
var arr = ['T@wn','D#nse Cr%wd','Cr#m#n#l M@st@m@nd'];

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
 l = '/[^'+pattern+']/';
 g = new RegExp(l,"gi");
 console.log(arr[i].replace(g,"").length);
}
```

The result will be:

```
4
11
18
```

The same variant, but without RegExp object, works fine:

```
var arr = ['T@wn','D#nse Cr%wd','Cr#m#n#l M@st@m@nd'];

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
 console.log(arr[i].replace(/[^@#%]/gi,"").length);
}
```

The result will be:

```
1
2
6
```

Can you explain the difference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var pattern = "@#%";
var arr = ['T@wn','D#nse Cr%wd','Cr#m#n#l M@st@m@nd'];

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
 l = '[^' + pattern + ']';
 g = new RegExp(l, "gi");
 console.log(arr[i].replace(g,"").length);
}
```

This line should be changed from:

```
l = '/[^' + pattern + ']/';
```

to:

```
l = '[^' + pattern + ']';
```

removing the surrounding `/` because you are passing in the regular expression pattern as a `string` to the `RegExp` constructor.

[Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) about these two types:

> You construct a regular expression in one of two ways:
>
> Using a regular expression literal, which consists of a pattern
>   enclosed between slashes, as follows:
>
> ```
> var re = /ab+c/;
> ```
>
> Regular expression literals provide compilation of
>   the regular expression when the script is loaded. When the regular
>   expression will remain constant, use this for better performance.
>
> Or calling the constructor function of the RegExp object, as follows:
>
> ```
> var re = new RegExp("ab+c");
> ```